# Enable hardware virtualization on Asus P8P67 motherboard?

Tags: virtualization, bios

I have the aforementioend motherboard and it appears that hardware virtualization is disabled on it (as according to vmware). I've looked at the bios options as well as the manual and haven't found any option to be able to turn it on. Am I buggered or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: hardware virtualization is called VT-d, and x86 virtualization is called VT-x.

Comment: what cpu on the motherboard?

Comment: Core i7, obviously socket 1155

Comment: If you're sure you CPU supports virtualization and your BIOS gives no options for enabling/disabling it, take a look at the product page for your motherboard and read up on the bios updates, maybe they exposed that option on a later version. You can also boot a Linux distro and run 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' and see if virtualization instructions are listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On most P8P67 motherboards (you don't specify which), this should be under Advanced - CPU Configuration - Intel Virtualization Technology.  If you don't have this option, then your processor probably doesn't support it.

Comment: thank you, it was there! Would have been wierd if it didn't, my older i5 and gigabyte mobo had support for it..