# How to enable hardware virtualization on Asus motherboard

Tags: intel-core-i7, hardware-virtualization

I have motherboard model: Asus MB P8Z68-V LX; LGA1155, Intel Z68 and processor Intel Core i7-2600 (LGA1155)

Searches on the Internet indicate hardware virtualization should be possible with these components, but I am not able to enable it.

There is no such option in the BIOS, I have also tried with the answer from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/322388/enable-hardware-virtualization-on-asus-p8p67-motherboard) but there is no path  Advanced - CPU Configuration - Intel Virtualization Technology (the last one is missing)

Can you please help me enable hardware virtualization?

Comment: According to your motherbaord's manual, that entry should be there, unless you have a CPU that doesn't support VT.  Have you tried updating your BIOS to the latest, and then resetting it to factory defaults?

Comment: FYI on my M4A78LT mobo, it was called "secure virtual machine" under the CPU tab. Sometimes I wish manufacturers wouldn't try to dumb things down.

Comment: It's also good to know that Intel named it "VT-d" what AMD named "IOMMU". Once you know what you are looking for, success is half-way...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I have an i7 2600K and P8Z68-V LE. It should be similar in your computer.
The hardware virtualization setting is located in
Advanced mode->Advanced tab->CPU Configuration-> Intel Virtualization Technology
According to this page, your i7 2600 will support VT-x and VT-d.
My "K" (unlocked version) only supports VT-X (so Intel can still sell Xeons) so yours may look a bit different, but it will be in the same place.
[image]

Comment: Note: F12 is to take a screenshot

Comment: screenshots in bios is.. fancy... well UEFI

Comment: I logged in to vote you up. thanks, I've been trying to find this option for  a while now, your screenshot made it bang on target for me to find it!

Comment: For future users like me, this will get Docker Desktop working correctly!

Answer (score 9):

The Asus Bios Utility said VT-x was supported but I couldn't find the setting to Enable Virtualization.

After an hour of head banging I noticed the scroll bars - little thin things, am sure the designer thought he was very clever.

Comment: So where did you enable it exactly?

Answer (score 6):

For the ASUS P9X79-WS with UEFI Bios ver. 4802 x64, enable VT-D is found under:

Advanced Mode\System Agent Configuration\Intel(R) VT-d,
not under Advanced\CPU Configuration\Intel Virtualization Technology as expected.

(Xeon E5-2620 v2. 2.1 GHZ supports VT-d)

I had to reset this setting after a power outage.  When I tried to re-start a virtual machine with ESXI 6.0 gave me the purple screen of death (Exception 14 Page Fault).  This fortunately fixed the issue.

Comment: I had to enable both. Crashed with any single of VT-x (error: lvmetad failed to connect) or VT-d (purple screen) enabled alone. THANKS Jack!! My setup: ATX-99 ii bios 0401 (uefi menu like you described) and Intel intel core i7-6900k, Ubuntu 17.04 with full-disk encryption

Comment: I didn't expect to find it under "System Agent Configuration" (what's the "System Agent"?). My board is an Asus Z87-C...

Answer (score 2):

According to your [motherbaord's manual](http://support.asus.com/download/download_item_mkt.aspx?slanguage=en-us&model=P8Z68-V%20LX), that entry should be there, unless you have a CPU that doesn't support VT.  Have you tried updating your BIOS to the latest, and then resetting it to factory defaults?

Also, perhaps check out [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) by [Gibson Research](http://grc.com) to find out if your hardware supports virtualization.

[image][image]